# Report Load Failed - IIS ,ASP.net with Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I have a published ASP.net application which has a **Web.config** file configured like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><configuration>
<appSettings>
 <add key="OLMSConnection" value="Data Source=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial       Catalog=databse;User ID=sa;Password=1234" />
 <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
 <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
 <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
 </appSettings>
 <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="OLMSDBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=sa;Password=1234" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
            <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" /><add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" /></assemblies></compilation>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="error.aspx" mode="Off" />
<httpHandlers><add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx"     type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
</httpHandlers></system.web>                
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="Index.aspx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
<handlers>
<add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET"   path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have these things installed:

> Windows 8.1
>   Crystal Report Runtime 13.0.14 for Visual Studio 2010
>   Google Chrome latest version
>   The ASP.net application was compiled and published in Visual Studio 2010

Now the problem is that when I try to load a crystal report through one of the module of the App it throws an error in the js alert window as...

> error: Failed report load

I can see that there are no errors in the Chrome console for any js related to Crystal reports.

I have doubts on the conflicts for version installed on my system and the assemblies version in the **Web.config** file

I can see no logs registered for this anywhere.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Crystal reports to run have some files in the `~/aspnet_client/` folder. Have you deployed those files as well?

Comment: Yeah i have copied the folder to my project root. They also appear in this location "C:\inetpub\wwwroot".

Comment: Please paste  the code where you call / load your report

Comment: @Furtiro Thankyou. I solved my problem by using the same version of Crystal Reports in which my ASP.net Application was compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using the same version of Crystal Reports in which my ASP.net application was compiled. As during the compilation the IDE writes the version details into the Web.config file.